# Internally listening for Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Say this is my provider model:

```
class Model extends ChangeNotifier {
  Product _product = Product(-1);

  Product get product => _product;

  void updateProduct(Product newProduct) {
    _product = newProduct;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class Product{
  final int id;

  Product(this.id);

  static Product of(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false);
    return model.product;
  }

  static void update(BuildContext context, Product newProduct) {
    final model = Provider.of<Model>(context, listen: false); // desc_1
    model.updateProduct(newProduct);
  }
}
```

`desc_1`: Setting `true` causes an error and keeping `false` doesn't update my widget tree.

I am updating it inside `lib/main.dart` file:

```
Product.update(context, Product(10)); // calling this should update all listeners
```

And I'm listening it inside `lib/home.dart` file:

```
final id = Product.of(context).id; // doesn't listen to changes
```

Can anyone tell me how can I make that happen.

---

PS: I know I can directly use `Provider.of(...)` directly in my `build()` method and get this model working but that way I always have to use 2 lines.

```
final provider = Provider.of<Model>(context);
final product = provider.product;
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want:

After your `ChangeNotifierProvider<Model>(...)` in your `main.dart` and before your `MaterialApp(...)` add this code:

```dart
... child: Builder(
        builder: (context){
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
    value: Provider.of<Model>(context).product
    child: MaterialApp(...));
    }
```

This way, you will add a Provider that will listen to the changes of the Model's Product.

Now make sure that `class Product extends ChangeNotifier{...}` and now instead of using `Product.of(context).id;` (which is not needed since there's a provider that handles that for you now) you would do:

`Provider.of<Product>(context).id;`

The function `update()` and `updateProduct()` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot in some days and will let you know.